# How do I fix a "TypeError" in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I'm totally new to Python just started learning a few days ago, and I tried to make a simple RPG code, but I have recently ran into a hiccup, it keep returning me TypeError: generate_damage() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'. Does anyone know what's going on?

**Main.py**

```
from Classes.game import player, bcolors

magic = [{"name": "Tackle", "cost": 1, "dmg": 4},
         {"name": "Ember", "cost": 3, "dmg": 6},
         {"name": "Leech", "cost": 4, "hp": +5, "dmg": 4},
         {"name": "Explosion", "cost": 5, "hp": -10, "dmg": 30}]

player(100, 20, 5, 10,magic)

print(player.generate_damage())
```

**Game.py**

```
import random 

class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'

class player:
    def __init__(self, hp, mp, atk, df, mag):
        self.maxhp = hp
        self.hp = hp
        self.maxmp = mp
        self.mp = mp
        self.atkw = atk - 10
        self.atks = atk + 10
        self.df = df
        self.mag = mag
        self.actions = ["Attack", "Magic"]

    def generate_damage(self):
        return random.randrange(self.atkw, self.atks)
```

I am having problems with the:

```
print(player.generate_damage())
```

As it keeps returning TypeError: generate_damage() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: Have you created a `player` instance?

Comment: Assign the player instance you created to a variable and invoke the function on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must instanlize a class, to use it's class method

```
magic = [{"name": "Tackle", "cost": 1, "dmg": 4},
         {"name": "Ember", "cost": 3, "dmg": 6},
         {"name": "Leech", "cost": 4, "hp": +5, "dmg": 4},
         {"name": "Explosion", "cost": 5, "hp": -10, "dmg": 30}]

p = player(100, 20, 5, 10,magic)

print(p.generate_damage())
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `generate_damage` is a method of class `Player`, you can run it only on player instance.
Try this:

```
p = Player(100, 20, 5, 10, magic) # init object p of class player

print(p.generate_damage())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of `player` first.

```
class Player:   # Note how I have changed the class to have an upper case P
    def __init__(self, hp, mp, atk, df, mag):
        self.maxhp = hp
        self.hp = hp
        self.maxmp = mp
        self.mp = mp
        self.atkw = atk - 10
        self.atks = atk + 10
        self.df = df
        self.mag = mag
        self.actions = ["Attack", "Magic"]

    def generate_damage(self):
        return random.randrange(self.atkw, self.atks)

player = Player(100, 20, 5, 10,magic)
print(player.generate_damage())
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling an instance method with the class name, you need to create an instance of that player class then call the instance method.
The correct code for your **main.py** would be:

```
from game import player, bcolors

magic = [{"name": "Tackle", "cost": 1, "dmg": 4},
         {"name": "Ember", "cost": 3, "dmg": 6},
         {"name": "Leech", "cost": 4, "hp": +5, "dmg": 4},
         {"name": "Explosion", "cost": 5, "hp": -10, "dmg": 30}]

p = player(100, 20, 5, 10,magic)

print(p.generate_damage())
```